# Proxyquire calling original file instead of stub

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, proxyquire

Hi I'm trying to mock a Model inside my controller using proxyquire. But for some reason when a try to inject a mock, the original file is being called.

This is how my model is being required inside the controller:

```
var Product = require('./product.model');
```

And this is how I', trying to stub the model

```
  var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru().noPreserveCache();
  var productsStub = {findAsync: sinon.stub()};
  productsStub.findAsync.resolves(mockProducts);
  var mockProducts = [{_id:'0001',title: 'title', price: 123, description: 'le description'}];
  var productController = proxyquire('./product.controller',{'./product.model':productsStub});
```

but when I run my tests I get this error

```
Running "mochaTest:unit" (mochaTest) task
>> Mocha exploded!
>> OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Product` model once compiled.
>>     at Mongoose.model (/Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:360:13)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/server/api/product/product.model.js:15:27)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>>     at normalLoader (/Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
>>     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>>     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/server/api/product/product.model.spec.js:1:15)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>>     at normalLoader (/Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
>>     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>>     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>>     at /Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:220:27
>>     at Array.forEach (native)
>>     at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:217:14)
>>     at MochaWrapper.run (/Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/tasks/lib/MochaWrapper.js:51:15)
>>     at /Users/victor/Documents/projects/estudo/mean/meanshop/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/tasks/mocha-test.js:86:20
```

My question is why I am getting this if in theory the original products.model.js module will not be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proxyquire does NOT stub not listed modules and they will be required as usual, so
it looks like you have more dependencies inside product.controller and they all are being normally required.

I can't find nice solution for this problem except providing full stub for proxyquire, e.g. add stubs for all files that required from directly imported files.

Comment: _except providing full stub for proxyquire_ | Can you please elaborate a bit more on that?